# Shadow DOM - Unable to Click element (Selenium webdriver nodejs)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I am attempting to click an element in a shadow dom. I am using Selenium Webdriver Nodejs. I currently get access the shadow root. I also can find an element. So I thought the last bit clicking it would be straight forward but cant find out how. There is not much support for Shadow Dom with nodejs.But cant work out how to click that element.

```
async function getshadowDOM(driver) {
// This gets the 1st Shadow Root
const shadowHost = await driver.findElement(By.css("#container > div.sf_common_comp-Page__header > div > xweb-shellbar"),3000);
const shadowRoot =  await driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowHost);

//This gets the 2nd Shadow Root
const shadowHost2nd = await shadowRoot.findElement(By.css("#shellbarContainer")); 
const shadowRoot2 =  await driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",shadowHost2nd);    

//Clicks the element in 2nd Shadow DOM
const elem = await shadowRoot2.findElement(By.css("div > div.ui5-shellbar-overflow-container.ui5-shellbar-overflow-container-left > button"));
await elem.click();
```

}
module.exports = getshadowDOM;

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution.
Used nodeJs + selenium.
It's work bad with return so i handle like this.

```js
const shadowHost = await driver.findElement(By.css("body > div.project > sn-component-va-web-client"));

const shadowRoot =  await driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowHost);

const elem = await shadowRoot.findElement(By.css("div.menu-item.contact-support-clicker"));

elem.click();
```

in my case its works.

Comment: Thanks for the response I will try it now. Shadow DOMs are a massive pain for both QA and dev it seems at moment

Comment: @user2886528 I have tried your solution and it didnt work. I have updated by code snippet above to your updated one. The issue is it fails with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'findElement')`